# Bootstrap Different input size different screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to control the form input size based on the screen size with t he default css or is this something I will have to create custom css to do? I would like the inputs to be larger on smaller screen size and then there default size on larger displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are already using twitter bootstrap.

I could elaborate on this issue more but Bootstrap does this the best.

So before I start please view : [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the viewport meta tag to your `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Second:

If you want some pieces Larger on smaller device use : `max-width` css property.

You can also use the `.img-responsive` Class made by Bootstrap. But basically all of that is written in the link I provided. If you have something more specific I'd love to help!

Good Luck on all.

Answer (score 0):

So this may not be the correct answer but the answer above doesn't explain too much with regards to actual code...

So, here's what I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-8" style="vertical-align: middle;align-self: center;">

        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search lots..." style="padding: 12px 20px; margin: 8px 0; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;" bind="@searchValue" />

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2" style="vertical-align: middle;align-self: center;">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent"
                onclick="@searchColumn(searchValue)">
            SEARCH
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2" style="vertical-align: middle;align-self: center;">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored"
                onclick=@(async () => await Reload()) id="btnReset">
            RESET
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Using bootstraps "row" and "col" classes, we can make a row, with columns inside it...

The class="col-sm-8" means, column, on a small device, with a column size of 8...

The column sizes range from 1 - 12

So if you had two columns with col-md-6 you would have two equal columns in a row...

By including two declarations you're telling bootstrap to use a certain column size on a certain screen size, defined by xs (extra small), sm (small), md (medium), lg (large)

You can have a look at this article I found which explains the different options in detail: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

extra: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp

Hope this helps :)